# Grep from a line to a line

Tags: grep

I have a file with hounded of thousands lines. I need to grep from a line to another line and include everything between these lines

i.e lines from `Wed Nov 25 23:08:01 GMT 2015` to `Wed Nov 25 23:59:24 GMT 2015`

```
[...]
abc
abc
abc
Wed Nov 25 23:08:01 GMT 2015
def
def
def
def
... (1000 lines with def)
Wed Nov 25 23:59:24 GMT 2015
xyz
xyz
xyz
[...]
```

Can you suggest what is the right grep expression?

Comment: Hello @Federi, Unfortunately, your question is not clear, please add samples of what you need to help you with.

Comment: Sorry about that. Added example on description. Hope is little bit more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of sed and grep should do the trick. Something like this:

```
sed '1,/Wed Nov 25 23:08:01 GMT 2015/d;/Wed Nov 25 23:59:24 GMT 2015/,$d' < file.txt | grep <yourstring>
```

Note that this example will not include the lines matching the dates, just everything in between them.

Comment: Seems that doesn't work for me

root@raspberrypi:/tmp# sed '1,/Wed Nov 25 23:08:01 GMT 2015/d;/Wed Nov 25 23:59:24 GMT 2015/,$d' < Mtelnet.txt | grep *
root@raspberrypi:/tmp#

Comment: Strange. I had tested that and it worked for me. Are you really grepping for "*", though? That would only find a match if the range of lines contained some text matching a filename in the current directory. Re-reading your edited post though, it looks like you need to display every single line between the two dates. If that's the case, you don't need the grep at all, so just get rid of everything from the "|" onwards in my example.

Comment: Not to mention that since you're already using `sed`, you don't need grep anyway.  Just tack on `;/yourstring/!d` into the end of the `sed` command arg.  This deletes any lines not matching `yourstring`.

Comment: Yes, good point, Wildcard: there's no need for grep either way. So if the OP needs to search within the range after all, your extra sed bit does the trick.

Comment: With this string it works :)

sed '1,/Wed Nov 25 23:08:01 GMT 2015/!d;/Thu Nov 26 00:30:24 GMT 2015/,$d' Mtelnet.txt > MTelent_MN.txt

Answer (score 1):

I can't suggest a `grep` expression, because this isn't what `grep` is for.

I would suggest instead using `perl` and a range operator:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <> ) {  
    print if m/Wed Nov 25 23:08:01 GMT 2015/ .. /Wed Nov 25 23:59:24 GMT 2015/;
}
```

Which if formatted as a one liner becomes:

```
perl -ne 'print if m/Wed Nov 25 23:08:01 GMT 2015/ .. /Wed Nov 25 23:59:24 GMT 2015/'
```

Note - it does text based matching, not numeric (as with regex). It would be possible to convert these dates and use time based.

You could do numerically like this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

my $start = Time::Piece->strptime( 'Nov 25 23:00:00 GMT 2015',
    '%b %d %H:%M:%S GMT %Y' );
my $end = Time::Piece->strptime( 'Nov 25 23:59:00 GMT 2015',
    '%b %d %H:%M:%S GMT %Y' );

my $last_timestamp;
while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp($line);
    my $timestamp =
        eval { Time::Piece->strptime( $line, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S GMT %Y' ) };
    $timestamp //= $last_timestamp;
    if ( $timestamp > $start and $timestamp < $end ) { 
        print $line,"\n";
    }
    $last_timestamp = $timestamp;
}

__DATA__
[...]
abc
abc
abc
Wed Nov 25 23:08:01 GMT 2015
def
def
def
def
... (1000 lines with def)
Wed Nov 25 23:59:24 GMT 2015
xyz
xyz
xyz
[...]
```

(Note - dates don't stringwise match your input - we're parsing them into numeric values, and checking within range).

Comment: I'm not confident with pearl scripting but it sounds really interesting. I'll have a look for sure! Thanks for that

Comment: `perl` is an extremely useful tool - it can do pretty much all of what `awk`/`sed`/`grep` can, as well as being a full blown programming language as well. It's worth the time of learning.